# GET parent theme throws 500 error in console, site works fine

Tags: child-theme, 500-internal-error

I have a storefront site with a storefront-child theme. Everything works fine except I have an annoying 500 in the console.

`GET https://fubar.net/wp-content/themes/storefront/?ver=5.3 
net::ERR_ABORTED 500`

Everything is enqueued correctly. Is this an .htaccess thing?

Comment: You can try https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/